# Why use Abstract Base Class instead of a regular class with NotImplemented methods?

Tags: python-2.7, oop, abstract-class

I've used ABC's in Python to enforce coding to a particular interface. However, it seems that I can achieve essentially the same thing by just creating a class whose methods are not implemented and then inheriting and overriding in actual implementations. Is there a more Pythonic reason for why ABC's were added, or was this just to make this coding pattern more prominent in the language?

Below is a code snippet I wrote that implements my "NotImplemented" scheme to define an abstract "optimizer" interface:

```
class AbstractOptimizer(object):
    '''
    Abstract class for building specialized optimizer objects for each use case.   
    Optimizer object will need to internally track previous results and other data so that it can determine the 
    truth value of  stopConditionMet(). 

    The constructor will require a reference argument to the useCaseObject, which will allow the optimizer
    to set itself up internally using fields from the use case as needed. There will need to be a close coupling between
    the optimizer code and the use case code, so it is recommended to place the optimizer class definition in the same module
    as the use case class definition.

    Interface includes a constructor and four public methods with no arguments: 

    0) AbstractOptimizer(useCaseObject) returns an instance of the optimizer
    1) getNextPoint() returns the current point to be evaluated 
    2) evaluatePoint(point) returns the modeling outputs "modelOutputs" evaluated at "point" 
    3) scorePoint(evaluationResults,metric) returns a scalar "score" for the results output by evaluatePoint according to metric. NOTE: Optimization is set up as a MINIMIZATION problem, so adjust metrics accordingly.
    4) stopConditionMet(score) returns True or False based on whatever past result are needed for this decision and the current score. If score = None, it is asumed to be the start of the optimization.
    5) getCurrentOptimalPoint() returns currently optimal point along with its iterationID and score

    The calling workflow will typically be: getNextPoint() -> evaluatePoint() -> scorePoint -> stopConiditionMet -> repeat or stop

    '''


    def __init__(self, useCaseObject):
        '''
        useCaseObject is a reference to use case instance associated with the optimizer.
        This optimizer will be "coupled" to this use case object.

        '''
        return NotImplemented

    def stopConditionMet(self,score = None):
        '''
        Returns True or False based on whether the optimization should continue.        
        '''
        return NotImplemented

    def getNextPoint(self):
        '''
        If stopConditionMet() evaluates to False, then getNextPoint() should return a point; otherwise, it should return None                
        '''
        return NotImplemented

    def evaluatePoint(self,point):
        '''
        Returns the modeling outputs "modelOutputs" evaluated at the current point.
        Will utilize the linked 
        '''
        return NotImplemented

    def scorePoint(self,evaluationResults,metric):
        '''
        Returns a scalar "score" for the current results evaluated in at the current point (from evaluatePoint) based on the function "metric"
        Note that "metric" will likely need to be a closure with the evaluation results as bound objects.
        '''
        return NotImplemented

    def getCurrentOptimum(self):
        '''
        returns currently optimal point and it's score as a dictionary: optimalPoint = {"point":point,"score":score}
        '''
        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: You should raise `NotImplementedError`, [`NotImplemented` is a constant value related to comparison mechanism in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#NotImplemented). It has different semantic meaning.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Thanks! Good catch...that will force overriding. So what am I missing about ABCs if I change the above to NotImplementedErrors? Especially since Python 2 and 3 handle this differently?

Comment: [See docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) _A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden._ In your case, overriding just `__init__` is enough for subclass to instantiate.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski ah, I see. So quite a bit stronger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) discusses the rational behind all of this

> ...In addition, the ABCs define a minimal set of methods that establish the characteristic behavior of the type. Code that discriminates objects based on their ABC type can trust that those methods will always be present. Each of these methods are accompanied by an generalized abstract semantic definition that is described in the documentation for the ABC. These standard semantic definitions are not enforced, but are strongly recommended..

This above statement appears to be a key piece of information.  An `AbstractBaseClass` provides guarantees that cannot be guaranteed by a standard `object`. These guarantees are paramount to paradigms in OOP style development. Particularly **inspection**:

> On the other hand, one of the criticisms of inspection by classic OOP theorists is the lack of formalisms and the ad hoc nature of what is being inspected. In a language such as Python, in which almost any aspect of an object can be reflected and directly accessed by external code, there are many different ways to test whether an object conforms to a particular protocol or not. For example, if asking 'is this object a mutable sequence container?', one can look for a base class of 'list', or one can look for a method named '**getitem**'. But note that although these tests may seem obvious, neither of them are correct, as one generates false negatives, and the other false positives.
>
> The generally agreed-upon remedy is to standardize the tests, and group them into a formal arrangement. This is most easily done by associating with each class a set of standard testable properties, either via the inheritance mechanism or some other means. Each test carries with it a set of promises: it contains a promise about the general behavior of the class, and a promise as to what other class methods will be available.
>
> This PEP proposes a particular strategy for organizing these tests known as Abstract Base Classes, or ABC. ABCs are simply Python classes that are added into an object's inheritance tree to signal certain features of that object to an external inspector. Tests are done using isinstance() , and the presence of a particular ABC means that the test has passed.

So while yes you can use an object and mimic the behavior of an ABCMeta class, the point of the ABC meta class it reduce boilerplate, false positives, false negatives, and provide guarantees about the code that otherwise would not be possible to guarantee without heavy lifting by you, the developer.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This was helpful!